# Should we start a transaction for burninating [transactional]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request, synonym-request

[transactional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/transactional) looks more a type-squatted tag than anything else.

Should it be burninated? Or can it be made an alias for [transactions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/transactions) automatically moving all ~600 questions tagged?

Comment: Alternative: *"should we rollback [transactional]?"* -> I vote for the alias option myself. Quite a few of the questions in the list are Java-oriented and even Java-Spring and there the term "transactional" is quite common.